# How to give a provider to a React <Route>?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to provide some data to my React Routes with the help of Provider and my others stores.

```
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Route path="/" element={HomePage} />
      </Provider>
      <Provider store={store2}>
        <Route path="/about" element={AboutPage} />
      </Provider>
      <Provider store={store3}>
        <Route path="/review" element={ReviewPage} />
      </Provider>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

But when I run my app it gives me the next error : `[Provider] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`.

How can use my provider inside my Routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the structure and wrap your `Router` inside each `Provider` as you can't have anything else than `Route` inside   component.

Also in React Router Dom V6, you need to render the element eg
`<Homepage />`

The code can look like this:

```
<>
  <Provider store={store}>
     <Router>
       <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
       </Routes>
     </Router>
   </Provider>
   <Provider store={store2}>
     <Router>
       <Routes>
           <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
       </Routes>
     </Router>
   </Provider>
  </>
```

---

*The latest update was to render the 'element' in eact-router-dom V6 as pointed out by @Ergis in the comments*

Comment: I did try this method already and the error that is being returned is : " Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Comment: If you are using **react-router-dom** version **6**, you need to 'render' the 'element': `<Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />` (so, `<HomePage />` not `HomePage`)

Comment: @Ergis you are absolutely right, that is one of the miss. Will update and credit you

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, wrapped all the elements from the route in the Provider that need it.

```
`  
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Provider> <HomePage/> </Provider>} />
        <Route path="/review" element={<Provider> <ReviewPage/> </Provider>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<Provider> <AboutPage/> </Provider>} />
    </Routes>
 `
```